how to go about cleaning my AC evaporator coil(indoor) and can i change the size of filter?
so my evaporator coil is gunked up with nasty looking build up and the original filter size is some nonexistant size so what i can buy just lets everything past it. Also the housing seems more to hold the filter from falling outward instead of keeping it from being sucked in. So can i change the filter housing size from 20x29x1 to say 20x25x1 with foam or something else? The evaporator is an A style with the center sealed off(the sides of the A-radiator and the center are one piece) and it mounts on top of the blower.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Read the instructions and look for a tutorial on youtube about cleaning your evaporator coil.  I suggest you remove that from the question.  Also look in the instructions for air flow and filter requirements, that will guide any modifications you make to the filter housing.  YOu want a 15% reduction.  May be ok, may not.   Include that info in the question.  Add a photo of the filter housing for advice on how to modify it.   It's usually easy to do

go to hardware store and buy spray, made for cleaning the coil
as for filter, cut and instal a wire mesh to hold it

is the spray fine with the blower underneath? all videos i have found show the blower not underneath
